# OpenTSDB HTTP API programming

Tags: http, opentsdb

Someone has developed some OpenTSDB application to interface with HTTP API Rest?
I'm new both to OpenTSDB and both to HTTP programming.

Answer (score 2):

Check out openTSDB2.0 documentation : [opneTSDB documetation](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html) It has better support for adding and scanning nodes via HTTP api.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for OpenTSDB clients. You will find a list of these on the [Resources page](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/resources.html).

If you want to monitor generic server statistics, these might already be implemented by one of the [utilities](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/utilities/index.html), like tcollector. We use scollector, which is a part of Bosun (see the Resources page above).

Answer (score 1):

Check the Documentation for OpenTSDB [HTTP API](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/index.html). Scroll down to `API Endpoints` section, you will find enpoint URLs for `put`,`aggregators`,`query`,`search`, etc